# Overwriting a formula in Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Here is the formula in question.

`.Range("F5").Formula = "=SUMPRODUCT(--(I23:I29>='Raw Data'!K2),--(I23:I29<='Raw Data'!K3))"`

This works fine, but what I want is instead of `I23:I29`, I want it so that when I did a "lastrow" formula in excel VBA, it will replace the I29, with the I and whatever the response in the last row actually is.

I figured that to make this happen I'd have to break the parentheses, but I wasn't sure if it was the correct thing to do.

What I thought I'd have to do is this:

`.Range("F5").Formula = "=SUMPRODUCT(--(I23:I" & lastrow">='Raw Data'!K2),--(I23:I" & lastrow"<='Raw Data'!K3))"`

But it doesn't look right. And Excel is giving me a redline for it as well, so I know I'm not doing it correctly.  Can someone help me figure out this little nightmare?

Comment: close: `.Range("F5").Formula = "=SUMPRODUCT(--(I23:I" & lastrow & ">='Raw Data'!K2),--(I23:I" & lastrow & "<='Raw Data'!K3))"`

Comment: done, and explained what you missed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close - watch out, and make sure the `&` are between every part of the string build:

`.Range("F5").Formula = "=SUMPRODUCT(--(I23:I" & lastrow & ">='Raw Data'!K2),--(I23:I" & lastrow & "<='Raw Data'!K3))"`